# Create PostgreSQL schemas before create_all function start creating the tables in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am starting to develop an application with Flask and PostgreSQL for my back-end and I am using PostgreSQL schemas.

My problem is that, when I call the `database.create_all()` function, SQLalchemy thrown me an error because the schema doesn't exist.

I trying to create the required schemas before the creation process start, using SQLAlchemy events and CreateSchema, but I don't understand well how to use the `CreateSchema`, with the next code:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema


database = SQLAlchemy()

@listens_for(database.metadata, 'before_create')
def create_schemas(target, b, **kw):
    CreateSchema('app')
    database.session.commit()
```

The listener is called, but the error still persist. The schema isn't being created in the database.

**NOTE:**
The database is initialized with the Flask application instance in another module as following:

```
from .model import database
database.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    database.create_all()
```

So, I am not getting any problem related to application context.

**EDIT:**

`CreateSchema` represent a `CREATE SCHEMA` sql statement, that must be executed with `database.session.execute(CreateSchema('app'))`.

Now I realize that the listener is called every time one table is created, throwing the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) schema "app" already exists
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fast way I solved my problem was creating the schemas right before I call **`database.create_all()`**. I used the statement **`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name`** that creates a schema just if it doesn't exist. This statement is just available starting from PostgreSQL 9.3

```
# my model module
def create_schemas():
    """ Note that this function run a SQL Statement available just in
        PostgreSQL 9.3+
    """

    database.session.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name')
    database.session.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name2')    
    database.session.commit()
```

I initializing the database and calling the function from another module:

```
 from .model import database, create_schemas

 database.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        create_schemas()
        database.create_all()
```

Well, this is a solution that works for my specific situation.